# spawn & drag of SVG elements - approach

Tags: javascript, svg, clone, element, draggable

I am on my learning curve for Javascript/SVG combo (animating and making interactive SVGs).

I wanted to create a code snippet where menu elements ("inventory") can be dragged over to the main screen ("canvas") while the originating element would remain in its place (as if one would move a copy of it off the original element).

Here I crafted the code snippet as best as I could:
http://codepen.io/cmer41k/pen/f2b5eea274cdde29b0b2dc8a2424a645

So I sort of managed to do something but its buggy:

1. I could deal with 1 copy and making it draggable, but then I don't know how to deal with IDs for all those spawning elements, which causes dragging issues
2. I fail to understand how to make it work indefinitely (so that it can spawn any amount of circles draggable to canvas)
3. Draggable elements in canvas often overlap and I fail to attach the listeners the way they don't overlap so that the listener on the element I am dragging would propagate "through" whatever other elements there;(

**Question is basically - can someone suggest logic that I should put into this snippet so that it was not as cumbersome. I am pretty sure I am missing something here;( (e.g. it should not be that hard is it not?)**

HTML:

```
<body>
<svg id="svg"
  height="800"
  width="480"
    viewbox="0 0 480 800"
    preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
>
    <rect id="canvasBackground" width="480" height="480" x="0" y="0"/>
    <rect id="inventoryBackground" width="480" height="100" x="0" y="480"/>


<g id="inventory">
<path id="curve4" class="inventory" d="M60,530 A35,35 0 1,1 60,531" />
<path id="curve3" class="inventory" d="M150,530 A35,35 0 1,1 150,531" />
<path id="curve2" class="inventory" d="M240,530 A35,35 0 1,1 240,531" />
<path id="curve1" class="inventory" d="M330,530 A35,35 0 1,1 330,531" />
</g>

<g id="canvas">
</g>

</svg>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
// define meta objects
var drag = null;

// this stores all "curves"-circles
var curves = {};
var canvas = {};
var inventory = {};

window.onload = function() {

        // creates the curve-circles in the object and at their initial x,y coords
        curves.curve1 = document.getElementById("curve1");
        curves.curve1.x = 0;
        curves.curve1.y = 0;
        curves.curve2 = document.getElementById("curve2");
        curves.curve2.x = 0;
        curves.curve2.y = 0;
        curves.curve3 = document.getElementById("curve3");
        curves.curve3.x = 0;
        curves.curve3.y = 0;
        curves.curve4 = document.getElementById("curve4");
        curves.curve4.x = 0;
        curves.curve4.y = 0;
        canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        inventory = document.getElementById("inventory");

        // attach events listeners

        AttachListeners();
}

function AttachListeners() {
    var ttt = document.getElementsByClassName('inventory'), i;
    for (i = 0; i < ttt.length; i++) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("inventory")[i].onmousedown=Drag;
    document.getElementsByClassName("inventory")[i].onmousemove=Drag;
    document.getElementsByClassName("inventory")[i].onmouseup=Drag;
    }
}

// Drag function that needs to be modified;//
function Drag(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        var t = e.target, id = t.id, et = e.type;  m = MousePos(e);

            if (!drag && (et == "mousedown")) {

                if (t.className.baseVal=="inventory") { //if its inventory class item, this should get cloned into draggable?
                    copy = t.cloneNode(true);
                    copy.onmousedown=copy.onmousemove=onmouseup=Drag;
                    inventory.insertBefore(copy, inventory.firstChild);
                    drag = t;
                    dPoint = m;
                } 
                if (t.className.baseVal=="draggable")   { //if its just draggable class - it can be dragged around
                    drag = t;
                    dPoint = m;
                }

            }
        // drag the spawned/copied draggable element now
            if (drag && (et == "mousemove")) {
                curves[id].x += m.x - dPoint.x;
                curves[id].y += m.y - dPoint.y;
                dPoint = m;
                curves[id].setAttribute("transform", "translate(" +curves[id].x+","+curves[id].y+")");  
            }

        // stop drag
            if (drag && (et == "mouseup")) {
                t.className.baseVal="draggable";
                drag = null;
            }
}



// adjust mouse position to the matrix of SVG & screen size
function MousePos(event) {
        var p = svg.createSVGPoint();
        p.x = event.clientX;
        p.y = event.clientY;
        var matrix = svg.getScreenCTM();
        p = p.matrixTransform(matrix.inverse());
        return {
            x: p.x,
            y: p.y
        }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were close. You had a couple of bugs. Eg.

```
copy.onmousedown=copy.onmousemove=onmouseup=Drag;
```

should have been:

```
copy.onmousedown=copy.onmousemove=copy.onmouseup=Drag;
```

And `drag = t` should have been `drag = copy` (?)

Also you were appending the clones to the inventory section, when I think you intended to append them to the "canvas" section.

But there were also also some less-obvious mistakes that were contributing to the unreliableness.  For example, if you attach the mousemove and mouseup events to the inventory and clone shapes, then you will won't get the events if you drag too fast.  The mouse will get outside the shape, and the events won't be passed to the shapes. The fix is to move those event handlers to the root SVG.

Another change I made was to store the `x` and `y` positions in the DOM for the clone as `_x` and `_y`. This makes it easier than trying to keep them in a separate array.

Anyway, here's my modified version of your example which works a lot more reliably.

```js
// define meta objects
var drag = null;

var canvas = {};
var inventory = {};
 
window.onload = function() {
  
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
 inventory = document.getElementById("inventory");
  
 // attach events listeners
 AttachListeners();
}

function AttachListeners() {
 var ttt = document.getElementsByClassName('inventory'), i;
 for (i = 0; i < ttt.length; i++) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("inventory")[i].onmousedown=Drag;
 }
    document.getElementById("svg").onmousemove=Drag;
 document.getElementById("svg").onmouseup=Drag;
}

// Drag function that needs to be modified;//
function Drag(e) {
    var t = e.target, id = t.id, et = e.type;  m = MousePos(e);
  
 if (!drag && (et == "mousedown")) {
    
  if (t.className.baseVal=="inventory") { //if its inventory class item, this should get cloned into draggable?
      copy = t.cloneNode(true);
   copy.onmousedown = Drag;
            copy.removeAttribute("id");
            copy._x = 0;
            copy._y = 0;
   canvas.appendChild(copy);
   drag = copy;
   dPoint = m;
  } 
  else if (t.className.baseVal=="draggable") { //if its just draggable class - it can be dragged around
   drag = t;
   dPoint = m;
  }
 }

    // drag the spawned/copied draggable element now
 if (drag && (et == "mousemove")) {
  drag._x += m.x - dPoint.x;
  drag._y += m.y - dPoint.y;
  dPoint = m;
  drag.setAttribute("transform", "translate(" +drag._x+","+drag._y+")"); 
 }
  
    // stop drag
 if (drag && (et == "mouseup")) {
  drag.className.baseVal="draggable";
  drag = null;
 }
}
         
  

// adjust mouse position to the matrix of SVG & screen size
function MousePos(event) {
  var p = svg.createSVGPoint();
  p.x = event.clientX;
  p.y = event.clientY;
  var matrix = svg.getScreenCTM();
  p = p.matrixTransform(matrix.inverse());
  return {
   x: p.x,
   y: p.y
  }
}
```

```css
/* SVG styles */
path
{
 stroke-width: 4;
 stroke: #000;
 stroke-linecap: round;
}

path.fill
{
 fill: #3ff;
}

html, body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 overflow:hidden;
 background-color: #fff; 
}
body {
 -ms-touch-action: none;
}
#canvasBackground {
 fill: lightgrey;
}
#inventoryBackground {
 fill: grey;
}
.inventory {
  fill: red;
}
.draggable {
  fill: green;
}
svg {
    position: fixed; 
   top:0%; 
   left:0%; 
   width:100%; 
   height:100%;  
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg"
  height="800"
  width="480"
 viewbox="0 0 480 800"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
>
 <rect id="canvasBackground" width="480" height="480" x="0" y="0"/>
 <rect id="inventoryBackground" width="480" height="100" x="0" y="480"/>
  

<g id="inventory">
<path id="curve4" class="inventory" d="M60,530 A35,35 0 1,1 60,531" />
<path id="curve3" class="inventory" d="M150,530 A35,35 0 1,1 150,531" />
<path id="curve2" class="inventory" d="M240,530 A35,35 0 1,1 240,531" />
<path id="curve1" class="inventory" d="M330,530 A35,35 0 1,1 330,531" />
</g>
  
<g id="canvas">
</g>

</svg>
```

Comment: Hey Paul, thank you so much;) I went through it step by step and now I have much better understanding how to do these things.